# None Value with Python tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am reading from a database and I am using `ttk.Entry` widgets to display the database data. I want the user to see the values and if they want to, change them.

But when a database's value is Null (`None` value for Python) the Entry widget displays the word "None" and not a `None` value. Is there any way to have a `None` value at the Entry widget or I have to compare using the word `"None"` hoping that the user will not use it?

The code just shows the Entry display of a "None" value:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

entry_value = StringVar()
entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_value)
entry.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
ttk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

myvalue = None
entry_value.set(myvalue)
print('same values') if myvalue == entry_value.get() else print('different values')
print('myvalue is None') if myvalue is None else print('myvalue is not None')
print('entry_value is None') if entry_value.get() is None else print('entry_value is not None')
print('entry_value is the word None') if entry_value.get() == 'None' else print ('entry_value is not thr word None')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean "hoping that the user will not use it"? Just do `if myvalue is None: entry_value.set('')`

Comment: How do you tell word None from the None value?

Comment: you're getting the value about one millisecond after creating the entry widget. I don't think the user can type that fast.

Comment: If this code doesn't accurately reproduce your problem, please show code that does. See [mcve]

Comment: @Rawing: This is making much easier. A good workaround

Comment: @Bryan: the code shows that a None value at Entry widgets is treated  like the word 'None'.

Comment: @Rawing I think that comment needs to be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter widgets cannot represent the value `None`. Tkinter is just a thin python wrapper around a tcl interepter, and the tcl language has no notion of `None` or a null value. Since `str(None)` returns the string `"None"`, that is what the widget is set to when you give it the value of `None`.

You'll have to come up with some custom way to handle that yourself, such as inserting an empty string if the value is actually `None`.